# Removing pip cache after installing dependencies in Docker image

Tags: python, linux, docker, pip

I noticed that docker images may be large because of keeping pip cache in `/root/.cache/pip`. I know I can remove this directory after all my dependencies are installed in my docker image. What I'm not sure is how this relates to docker's BuildKit which allows quicker installation by using cache. Are these two somehow related? So if I'd like to benefit from BuildKit is it safe to remove `/root/.cache/pip`? My question is motivated by heavy python dependencies like torch and nvidia which may occupy few GB. Removing pip cache may decrease the size of the image by 2-3 GB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better solution here is to not cache the packages in the first place (you're not going to need them anyway; the image build process won't benefit from them unless you're doing something terrible).

The simplest solution is to just pass `--no-cache-dir` to your `pip` invocations, and it won't cache the packages to disk in the first place. Alternatively, you can drop a `pip.conf` containing:

```
[global]
no-cache-dir = True
```

to `/etc/pip.conf` in the container to disable it globally (without needing to pass the switch each time). Note that if your image ships with a version of `pip` prior to 19.0.1 the `pip.conf` solution is buggy; if that's the case, you can use `--no-cache-dir` command line switch manually to update `pip` to a post-19.0.1 version, then modify `/etc/pip.conf` to add the extra line if needed.

Bonus: You may want to expand the `pip.conf` to:

```
[install]
compile = no

[global]
no-cache-dir = True
```

where the `compile = no` tells `pip` not to compile the Python source files to bytecode on install; the benefit of pre-compiled bytecode is (slightly) faster startup, but by bloating your image, it will take longer to download/run it, so the cost to the Docker layer outweighs any savings for Python launch itself.

Lastly, add:

```
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

to your `Dockerfile` (can be combined with other `ENV` settings to avoid extra layers) near the top of the file. Where the `pip.conf` prevents compiling/writing bytecode on install, the environment variable prevents writing them at runtime (which would be a pointless exercise; when the container exits, the bytecode would be lost anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. In fact, the image size decreased a lot, in my case it was over 2GB! But the main question was how this relates to the docker's BuildKit feature? Clearing the pip cache has no side effects to the BuildKit? Or am I missing something from Your answer?

Comment: @JakubMałecki: I don't think BuildKit matters here. The main issue is that, if the cache is populated and not cleared *in the same build step*, then the cache is in the image, and it's a new layer that deletes the cache from view, but it's still bloating the prior layers and there's no way to avoid that once the prior layer has been bloated.